# Fullcalendar Not Working Other Methods Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm working with the Fullcalendar Vue. I want to click on the relevant event and take action. I can catch it with Watch or run a Function, but I can't go outside. What's the problem?

```
eventClick: function(info){
   console.log(info.event.id); // Console Log 25
   this.calendarEvent = info.event.id; // Not Write
   this.changeEventData(info.event.id); // Not Working (this.changeEventData is not a function)
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what the problem is. Are you getting a specific error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` object is not available in your scope. You can fix this by using an arrow function.

```
eventClick: info => {
   this.calendarEvent = info.event.id;
}
```